# Date range standards?

Tags: dates, formatting

I'd like to show a date range in a succinct way but also have it look good in other countries, are there any standards for formatting date ranges in other countries? So far for the US I've found that this seems the most correct...

```
Aug 2 - 9 2015
Aug 2 - Sept 15 2015
Aug 2 2015 - Jan 6 2016
```

Comment: This is really difficult because different countries format dates differently. It would help if you included more information on what you need it for

Comment: Oztaco sorry thats what im asking for... how do other countries format date ranges, or what are at least the common ways they do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which date format to use?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/12427/which-date-format-to-use)

Answer (score 1):

[This Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country) should be what you're looking for.

A good chunk of the countries use DMY format (i.e. 2 August 2015), so using that would cover a pretty large amount of people. Quite a few also use the YMD format (i.e. 2015-8-2), however, and America uses the MDY format (i.e. August 2, 2015 or ([less commonly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calendar_date#Gregorian.2C_month-day-year_.28MDY.29)) with an ordinal: August 2nd, 2015).

Also, each country differs in not only the order but the formatting as well. For example, some use only numbers, while some use the name of the month as well.

Luckily however, many programming languages and frameworks ([such as Microsoft .NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hh873ya(v=vs.90).aspx) and [Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661325/simpledateformat-and-locale-based-format-string)) have a built in formatter so that you don't have to format it by hand.

I couldn't find anything specifically about formatting date *ranges* in different cultures, though. However, the [EN dash](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm) is made for use in ranges (see [this answer](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/62575/hyphens-or-en-dashes-which-are-more-readable-when-used-in-number-ranges-for-nor/63376#63376)).

Answer (score 0):

Every computer has culture and lang settings that determine the date convention (either for short or long dates). For mobile, just show dates as users have configured in their phone settings. For web, you can show in the culture of the website, and that will be consistent with content.

Whatever you do, do not forget to include timezone if date range includes hours.

Answer (score 0):

To whomever stumbles here, there is now a function in browsers that handles this issue and includes preferences for many languages and regions.

See documentation for [Intl.DateTimeFormat.prototype.formatRange()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/formatRange) on MDN.

Example:

```
const date1 = new Date(Date.UTC(2023, 0, 10, 10))
const date2 = new Date(Date.UTC(2023, 0, 20, 10))

const fmten = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', {
  year: 'numeric',
  month: 'short',
  day: 'numeric',
})

const fmtde = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('de', {
  year: 'numeric',
  month: 'short',
  day: 'numeric',
})

console.log(fmten.formatRange(date1, date2))
// -> 'Jan 10 – 20, 1906'

console.log(fmtde.formatRange(date1, date2))
// -> '10.–20. Jan. 1906'
```